# Get enum name when value is known

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum that has different colors in it. I would like to pass some function an `int` and have it return the color name that is in the enum in that position.

What's the way to do this?

Comment: And why not pass the enum to the method? and What do you expect the result to be if the int passed in does not match a value of your enum?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
return ((MyEnumClass)n).ToString();
```

Comment: While I like Tomas's answer, this has the benefit of being to the point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 58):

Another option is to use the `GetName` static method:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnumClass), n);
```

This has the benefit that the code speaks for itself. It should be obvious that it returns the name of the enum (which may be a bit difficult to realize when you use for example the `ToString` method).

Comment: Helped me in a situation to fetch enum name from value on view page for checking roles for user to navigate to thepages respectively.

Answer (score 14):

In c# 6 you can use `nameof`.

```
nameof(YourEnum.Something)
```

results in:

```
something
```

Answer (score 7):

If your enum with colors is named `MyColorEnumName`, Try

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(MyColorEnumName),  enumColorValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you care about performance beware of using any of the suggestions given here: they all use reflection to give a string value for the enum.
If the string value is what you'll need most, you are better off using strings. If you still want type safety, define a class and a collection to define your "enums", and have the class echo its name in the ToString() override.

Comment: Why does so much apparently simple stuff in C# have painful performance implications?

Comment: Because it's a programming language?

Comment: It's not like this is a common operation -- enum names can't even contain spaces, so you'll rarely want to use them as "friendly names" for something.

Comment: How many milliseconds does it actually take to use reflection on an enum?  Unless you're doing it millions of times a second a loop, I bet it's not even measurable?

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the example to get Enum name based on the color value.**

```
  class Program
     {
          //Declare Enum
          enum colors {white=0,black=1,skyblue=2,blue=3 }
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          // It will return single color name which is "skyblue"
             string colorName=Enum.GetName(typeof(colors),2);

          //it will returns all the color names in string array.
          //We can retrive either through loop or pass index in array.
             string[] colorsName = Enum.GetNames(typeof(colors));

         //Passing index in array and it would return skyblue color name
             string colName = colorsName[2];

             Console.WriteLine(colorName);
             Console.WriteLine(colName);
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**((YourEnum)Value).ToString()**

For eg.

```
((MyEnum)2).ToString()
```

**Note:** Points to remember, your enum should be decorated by [Flag] and enum value must be greater than 0.