# Get Enum name based on the Enum value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, enums

I have declared the following Enum:

```
public enum AfpRecordId
{
    BRG = 0xD3A8C6,
    ERG = 0xD3A9C6
}
```

and i want to retrieve the enum object from is value:

```
private AfpRecordId GetAfpRecordId(byte[] data)
{
    ...                    
}
```

Call Examples:

```
byte[] tempData = new byte { 0xD3, 0xA8, 0xC6 };
AfpRecordId tempId = GetAfpRecordId(tempData);

//tempId should be equals to AfpRecordId.BRG
```

I would also like to use linq or lambda, only if they can give better or equals performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get enum name when value is known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327883/get-enum-name-when-value-is-known)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple:

- Convert the byte array into an `int` (either manually, or by creating a four byte array and using [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx))
- Cast the `int` to `AfpRecordId`
- Call `ToString` on the result if necessary (your subject line suggests getting the name, but your method signature only talks about the value)

For example:

```
private static AfpRecordId GetAfpRecordId(byte[] data)
{
    // Alternatively, switch on data.Length and hard-code the conversion
    // for lengths 1, 2, 3, 4 and throw an exception otherwise...
    int value = 0;
    foreach (byte b in data)
    {
        value = (value << 8) | b;
    }
    return (AfpRecordId) value;
}
```

You can use `Enum.IsDefined` to check whether the given data is actually a *valid* ID.

As for performance - check whether something simple gives you good enough performance before you look for something faster.

Comment: am i forced to convert the byte array to an int ? If i got it right the value "BRG = 0xD3A8C6" is not recognized as a byte[] ?

Comment: I don't think he's actually looking for a string (I thought that originally as well) If you look at the return type of his boiler plate method it returns a value of the enum

Comment: @Duncan_McCloud: Indeed, `0xd3a8c6` is an `int` literal, not a byte array. While there are probably other ways beyond converting the byte array to an int, they'd effectively boil down to something similar, and be more complicated. This code should be extremely fast, and it's nice and simple - what don't you like about it?

Comment: I like it. i am just trying to understand how it works at 100% :). Iam gonna using it just after my lunch break. Thank :)

Comment: @Duncan_McCloud: Basically, enums are maps from numbers to names. The numbers in your enum are `int` values, so you need to convert your byte array to an `int` to get the right number.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is of a known size (I'll assume the size is 3 as per your example) you can 
add the elements together and the cast the result to the enum

```
private AfpRecordId GetAfpRecordId(byte[] tempData){
    var temp = tempData[0] * 256*256 + tempData[1] * 256 +tempData[2];
    return (AfpRecordId)temp;
}
```

a different approach would be to use the shift operator instead

```
private AfpRecordId GetAfpRecordId(byte[] tempData){
    var temp = (int)tempData[0]<<16 + (int)tempData[1] * 8 +tempData[2];
    return (AfpRecordId)temp;
}
```

Comment: Note that this assumes `tempData` has three elements. That *may* be a valid assumption, but it may not be.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it does assume that (based on the sample code. I have updated so that the answer highlights the assumption. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `tempData` has 3 elements use `Enum.GetName (typeof (AfpRecordId), tempData[0] * 256*256 + tempData[1] * 256 +tempData[2])`.