# How can I retrieve Enum from char value?

Tags: c#, parsing, enums, char

I have the following enum

```
public enum MaritalStatus
{
    Married = 'M',
    Widow = 'W',
    Widower = 'R',
    Single='S'
}
```

In one function I have for exp: `'S'` , and I need to have `MaritalStatus.Single`.

How can I **get the enum from the character value**?
For string I found this solution, but it gets exception for Char.

```
YourEnum foo = (YourEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(YourEnum), yourString);
```

Comment: I imagine that when you are assigning the enums a char value, it is actually assigning them an int value, so if you convert the char to an int, you can then convert that int to the equivalent enum value.

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327883/get-enum-name-when-value-is-known

Comment: @AmeyKhadatkar - Though it is similar the difference is that in this question the `n` is a `char` and not an `int`

Comment: @GiladGreen If that is the case then vivek nuna 's answer is better

Comment: @AmeyKhadatkar no, it actually doesn't answer the question at all. For the `Char` value `'M'`, that answer would provide the `String` value `"Married"`, whereas the question is how to parse the `MaritalStatus` value `MaritalStatus.Married` from the `Char` value `'M'` (or `MaritalStatus.Widow` from `'R'`, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess found One solution for that:

```
   (MaritalStatus)Enum.ToObject(typeof(MaritalStatus), 'S')
```

It gets me **MaritalStatus.Single**

*Enum.ToObject(enumType, byte) is the signature.*

Answer (score 12):

The enum values, though defined with `char`s actually equal to the `int` representation of that char. It is as if you defined it as following:

```
public enum MaritalStatus
{
    Married = 77,
    Widow = 87,
    Widower = 82,
    Single=83
}
```

Convert `char` to `int` and then assign to the enum:

```
int m = 'M'; // char of `M` equals to 77
MaritalStatus status = (MaritalStatus)m;  

Console.WriteLine(status == MaritalStatus.Married); // True
Console.WriteLine(status == MaritalStatus.Single); // False
```

---

After playing with it a bit and putting it into a one liner I see that **even the conversion to an `int` is not needed**. All you need is to cast as the enum:

```
MaritalStatus status = (MaritalStatus)'M'; // MaritalStatus.Married
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to get the enum Name from value.

```
string name =   ((MaritalStatus)'S').ToString();
string enumName =  Enum.GetName(typeof(MaritalStatus), 'S');
```

In C# 6.0 you can use [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)

Comment: The `ToString` will work but I'm not sure how you can use the `nameof`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the enum value of the character by changing the charValue to string and then reading the first character and casting it to my ENUM type.

Looks like this in code :

```
( Marital Status ) ( charValue.ToString ( ) [ 0 ] )
```